# Warp speed and collisions

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, warp

When a star ship is traveling at warp 9.999, how can it quickly maneuver out of the way of planets? Since this is pretty dang fast, how far do sensors have to reach out ahead at that speed to help them maneuver without colliding with a planet, meteor or star?

Comment: Good question, keep them coming.

Comment: traveling through hyperspace ain't like dusting crops boy...oh wait, wrong show...

Comment: Space is mostly empty...space. Stars and planets don't jump around, and, unless they are hidden somehow, are visible from very long distances, with just plain old light. Say to your navigator "plot a course to..." the word plot implies staying away from "fixed objects" and staying outside planetary systems is a good way to avoid the smaller stuff. So you want a plot that goes around any star systems on the way. Unless you are passing through/near the center of the galaxy it's unlikely you will have to dodge very many.

Comment: Trelane made Gothos jump.

Comment: @Seeds - it's still a valid question though - while doing that is fine for "dodging" known objects there is still the risk you'll run into large floating rocks, especially Voyager, which is warping into completely uncharted space. You'd think if they were just relying on the low probability of hitting something it would have come up in the show at some stage...